# "Missing $ Inserted" error in math environment

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, compiling, arrays

I have the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
  A & B & A \land B\\
  \hline
  F & F & F\\
  F & T & F\\
  T & F & F\\
  T & T & T\\
\end{array}$$ 
\end{document}
```

Previously, I had the `{array}` wrapped in a `{displaymath}` environment, but in both cases, attempting to compile this gives me the following errors:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8 $$\begin{array}{cc|c}
```

and

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.15 \end{array}
                $$
```

My understanding was that this arose from using math symbols outside of a math environment, but haven't I put the `{array}` in a math environment as is? It still generates the PDF as I expect, and outputs a `.png` thanks to the `convert` instructions defined in my `{standalone}`, but the compiler insists on showing me each of these error messages twice per compile.

Comment: you can not use display constructs in `standalone` with those options, use `$` (you should not use `$$` in latex anyway but `\[` woud give the same error here)

Comment: Or use the `varwidth` option for `standalone`.